# Cannot find other desktop environments in software center

Tags: software-center, desktop-environments

I have just installed  Ubuntu 16.04 but I want to try a different desktop environment. [This link](http://www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/) shows how to install them but I cannot find anything in the software center. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You’d install for example XFCE from the terminal on Ubuntu or Linux Mint:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

The above command would give you the standard XFCE desktop environment. But if you want Xubuntu’s customized XFCE desktop environment instead:

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Log out of your Linux desktop after installing another desktop environment.

Then, when you see the login screen, click the session menu and select the desktop environment you want to use.